# Excel nested IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I need to create an IF formula based on data in 3 different columns and give a result of yes or no if certain conditions are met as follows:

```
If D2 = "Achieved" and  E2 = "NO"    then J2 = "YES"
If E2 = "Expires"  and  I2 > TODAY() then J2 = "YES"
If E2 = "Expires"  and  I2 < TODAY() then J2 = "NO"
If I2 = "Never Achieved"             then J2 = "NO"
```

I've tried various combinations of IFs and ANDs and I'm going round in circles at this point. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Search for examples of Excel `if` uses. If all else fails, read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it With OR,AND and Nested IF:

```
=IF(OR(AND(D2 = "Achieved", E2 = "NO"),AND(E2 = "Expires", I2 > TODAY())),"YES",IF(OR(I2 = "Never Achieved",AND(E2 = "Expires",  I2 < TODAY())),"NO","NO COMBO FOUND"))
```

Comment: Thank you (and Ralph) so much for the quick answers, works perfectly. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Martin79 Mark the one you ended up using as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer yesterday. Would you know if there is an easy way to modify the above so if D2 = "In Progress", then J2 = "No"? I've been trying various modifications but again, getting nowhere. Thanks again